# How can I get my connection string from SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have installed SQL Server Express, at the end of the installation it showed some connection string but I couldn't get it now. How can I get the connection string from SQL Server Express?

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

If you left it as default, the instance will be called SQLEXPRESS, your instance could be: localhost\SQLExpress

Comment: It's showing another error when I reset the test databases. This is that error "'Cannot open database "BizEconomyLicenseDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed."

Comment: That's a different problem.  Probably related to the users defined in your SQL server not being defined in your SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFolder\MyDataFile.mdf;Database=dbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/attach-a-database-file-on-connect-to-a-local-sql-server-express-instance/